# Convert Speex files to MP3, programatically?

Tags: php, mp3, speex

Is is there some sort of library that would allow me to convert a speex file to an mp3 file? If it were do-able from php that would be even better, but really anything would probably work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have [gstreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) available on your platform, it can do it for you provided you have the proper codecs installed.

On http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=61984 I found this piece of code for wma to mp3 conversion, you should be able to craft something similar for your needs:

> `gst-launch filesrc location=filename.wma ! spider ! lame ! filesink location=filename.mp3`