# How can I record audio in a Air Mobile App?

Tags: actionscript-3, mobile, air, audio-recording

I had searched for a long time and didn't found anything about it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AIR2 version of of the Galaxy-Tab1 device worked well when tested on 3years ago.

refer a following my code. I'll probably work well. Trust me on that.

Framework used here is the link.

WAVWriter:
[WAVWriter](http://code.google.com/p/ghostcat/source/browse/trunk/ghostcatfp10/src/ghostcat/media/WAVWriter.as?r=424)

ShineMP3Encoder:
[ShineMP3Encoder](http://code.google.com/p/flash-kikko/)

**This code is Skeleton, but Worked fine.**

```
import com.adobe.audio.format.WAVWriter;
import fr.kikko.lab.ShineMP3Encoder;
import flash.events.SampleDataEvent;
import flash.media.Microphone;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flash.events.Event;

var mp3encoder:ShineMP3Encoder;
var microphone:Microphone;
var isRecording:Boolean=false;
var soundRecording:ByteArray;

function startMicRecording():void 
{
    isRecording=true;
    soundRecording = new ByteArray();
    microphone=Microphone.getMicrophone();
    microphone.rate=44;
    microphone.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, gotMicData);
}

function stopMicRecording():void {

    isRecording=false;
    microphone.removeEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, gotMicData);
    soundRecording.position=0;

    convert2MP3();
}


function gotMicData(micData:SampleDataEvent):void 
{
    soundRecording.writeBytes(micData.data);
}

function convert2MP3():void
{
    var wavWrite:WAVWriter = new WAVWriter();
    wavWrite.numOfChannels=1;
    wavWrite.sampleBitRate=16;
    wavWrite.samplingRate=44100;

    var wav:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

    wavWrite.processSamples(wav, soundRecording, 44100,1);
    wav.position=0;

    /* 
     If the process is compressed into mp3 if you have big problems, 
     just as .wav format save. following code: 
     var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
     file.save(wav,"your_file_name.wav");
    */

    mp3encoder=new ShineMP3Encoder(wav);
    mp3encoder.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onEncoded);
    mp3encoder.start();
}

function onEncoded(e:Event):void 
{
    mp3encoder.mp3Data.position=0;
    mp3encoder.saveAs("your_file_name.mp3");
}
```

Comment: I would caution any MP3 compression on mobile platform.  I have tried the above approach on Android as well as iPhone, the compression take a long time for a one-minute audio, and the phone became slow and warm.

Comment: Really? 'll Have to be careful. Here in the past about the lack of any response by the client did not know that. I also never experienced such a Circumstances when tested and could not.

Comment: @TianzhenLin What you recomment instead of compressing to mp3?

Comment: For recording, Flash supports Nellymoser (the default), Speex, PCMA (for G.711 A-law), and PCMU (for G.711 μ-law).  I saw Speex to MP3 conversion in this SO thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306622/convert-speex-files-to-mp3-programatically